# Incompatibilidad entre Android Studio y el plugin de Gradle

Tags: android

> Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)

Comment: Bienvenido kato, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Antes de abrir tu solución prueba actualizar Android Studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también puedes seleccionar en el panel izquierdo en el panel de Graddle, busca clean da doble clic, luego puedes hacer una sincronización de las librerías, esto suele suceder cuando no está el ide actualizado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]